# Tag name using environment variables

Tags: github, release, github-actions, release-management

I want to create a release tag from a workflow with GitHub Actions using `actions/create-release@v1`. I am specifying the same value for the tag name and the release name, which is `v${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${PATCH}`, where `MAJOR`, `MINOR`, and `PATCH` are defined under `env` at the beginning of the yaml file before all jobs like this:

```
env:
  MAJOR: $(cat VERSION.txt | cut -d . -f 1)
  MINOR: $(cat VERSION.txt | cut -d . -f 2)
  PATCH: $(cat VERSION.txt | cut -d . -f 3)
```

Here is the part where I invoke the create-release action:

```
- name: Create Release
  uses: actions/create-release@v1
  env:
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # this token is created by Actions, no need to set it up ourselves
  with:
    tag_name: "v${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${PATCH}" #THIS DOESN'T CAST MAJOR, MINOR, PATCH
    release_name: "v${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${PATCH}"
```

This creates a tag name that is explicitly `v${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${PATCH}`. The environment variables are not converted to their values. When I use `v${{ env.MAJOR }}.${{ env.MINOR }}.${{ env.PATCH }}` instead, I get a not well-formed tag name.

When I echo `v${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${PATCH}`, I get the desired output, which is something like `v5.9.1`.

How can I make the tag name use the values of the environment variables ?

Comment: Without the section where you are setting these variables it's just guessing

Comment: I added the part where I define the major, minor, and patch

Comment: You can't set the env vars like that. Check out the docs here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, the syntax you are pointing works at a job level, meaning that I have to repeat it for each job, while setting the env key at the beginning of the yaml file before any job makes the environment variables available to all jobs. Also, the way I did seems to work for other actions in the same yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to one of the comments, I managed to make tag_name receive the value `v5.9.1`. I removed the `env` key at the beginning of the yaml file, and created a step `get_version` with the following:

```
   - name: Get version
      id: get_version
      run:  |
        MAJOR=$(cat VERSION.txt | cut -d . -f 1)
        MINOR=$(cat VERSION.txt | cut -d . -f 2)
        PATCH=$(cat VERSION.txt | cut -d . -f 3)
        VERSION="v${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${PATCH}"
        echo "::set-output name=version::${VERSION}"
```

then I modified the create release step :

```
- name: Create release
  uses: actions/create-release@v1
  env:
     GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  tag_name: ${{ needs.get_version.outputs.version }} 
  release_name: ${{ needs.get_version.outputs.version }}
   draft: false
   prerelease: false
```